# what does the error "stage value is invalid" mean in MongoDB and how do I fix it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to use lookup to join two collections in MongoDB compass, but I get this error and I have no clue how to fix it. I am totally new to MongoDb, please help!

```js
{
  from: power_plants,
  localField: power_plant_id,
  foreignField: plant_id,
  as: result
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgaBZ.jpg)

i tired this code as well but it still doesnt work.

```js
db.greenhouse.aggregate([
    { $lookup:
        {
           from: "power_plants",
           localField: "power_plant_id",
           foreignField: "plant_id",
           as: "result"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: it means that you've specified stage in invalid format. In the above case, you missed a top level field: `$lookup`

Comment: @dododo thank you for the response! I added that but it still doesnt work (I edited my second code block). I am using compass to add the stage. I greatly appreciate any help

Comment: what does it mean "doesnt work"?

Comment: @dododo i mean the "stage value invalid" error is still there

Comment: that is not true, see https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vhi5reSaM25

Comment: @DaibataRoy If you try the `$lookup` from the `Compass` built-in `mongosh`, does it work?  If not, what is the error?

Comment: I'm also wondering if you just put quotes (`"`) around all of your values, if `Compass` will accept the stage.

Comment: Have same problem as author, do @DaibataRoy you solved the problem by using lookup in mongo compass?

Answer (score 4):

Do not forget to use the "" on the values like this

```
{
  from: "user",
  localField: "userId",
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: "userInfo"
}
```

Comment: The OP appears to have tried both with and without the `"` on the values.